# facebook login doesn't hold

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I finally got my facebook login working, so I can retrieve information from a user

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once 'facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '19582352346693',
        'secret' => '44c21dde8d502ega23g287a751dea',
        'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

?>

<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<head>

<title>Picture</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php 

if($user_id) {

  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try {
    $test = null;
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    //$test = $user_profile['id'];
    echo "id: " . $user_profile['id'];

  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {

  // No user, print a link for the user to login
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}

?>

</div> 

</body>

</html>
```

All this code, will give me a login, since I am not logging in to the APP(Authenticated). When I press the button, I can then see my information, since I echo it.

When I then press another button on my page:

```
<form action="<?php echo 'single_picture.php?argument=' . $picture_id ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote!">
</form>
```

I open the same page again, but the login button just shows up again and forgot all about I am logging in.

I thought the if / else was checking if I am logging in.

I also tried printing out my access token

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

I then put it into: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

This says the access token is valid for an hour

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to store the access token you get from facebook into some place. be it the session, a databse table or a simple text file. Before the neyt request you set this token (`$facebook->setAccessToken($saved_access_token);`), as long as it's still valid.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for answer. I have been having troubles getting session to work, but I will try some more. Many users will be using the app at the same time, so I am having a hard time figuring out how to get it to work with database or txt.

Comment: Since the validity of the token is 1 hour anyway, session should be appropriate to store the token. Call `session_start();` before any other code and assign values with `$_SESSION['token'] = $facebook->getAccessToken();`. Before making a fb request, check if `$_SESSION['token']` contains a value; if yes set this value else you can directly redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all your grammar so confusing. 
I think you forgot to use sesion_start

```
<?php session_start() ?>
```

or check for cookies.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I already had it, but thank you for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not what you want, you gave me your problem and I am giving you a different answer but please take this as a suggestion. What I do when using Facebook login is I create my own login system and for Facebook users I have another table that stores the users Facebook id, then I only use the Facebook API to check against my database whether or not that information is valid. If it is, then I log the user in. If it is not then I send them either to an error page or to a sign up page.